# Limit the number of Loops then pass it to next process

Tags: php, loops

I dont know if my title is correct. Im not an expert on PHP, But here's what i need to do.

I have an autoupdate php code/script that updates a product on every stores on our database. I run it on cron job but it giving me a timeout error.

I am thinking that if its possible on cron job or php, that when i run the autoupdate script, it will count how many loops/update process it will do then the script will run the updates on every 100 stores and run the next after let say 2minutes.

Can i achieve it on PHP and cron Job? How can i make it? Can someone give me the idea.

Comment: You may want to read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you'd like the work done ASAP, don't use cron. Cron is good for things that need to happen at specific times. It's often abused to simulate a background process that would ideally process work as soon as work appears. You should probably write a daemon that runs continuously. (Note: you could also look at a message/work-queue type system, there are nice libraries out there to do this too)

You can write a daemon from scratch using the pcntl functions (since you don't care about multiple worker processes, it's super-easy to get a process running in the background.), or cheat and just make a script that runs forever and run it via screen, or leverage some solid library code like PEAR's System:Daemon or nanoserv

Once the daemonization stuff is taken care of, all you really care about is having a loop that runs forever. You'll want to take care that your script doesn't leak memory, or consume too many resources.

Generally, you can do something like:

```
<?PHP
// some setup code 
while(true){
    $todo = figureOutIfIHaveWorkToDo();
    foreach($todo as $something){
        //do stuff with $something
        //remember to clean up resources so you don't leak memory!
        usleep(/*some integer*/);
    }
    usleep(/* some other integer */); 
}
```

And it'll work pretty well.